# "Here Document" as a Single Line Command?

Tags: shell, here-document, here-string

I have this command to run a checksum in some software I want to install:

```
echo "85762db0edc00ce19a2cd5496d1627903e6198ad850bbbdefb2ceaa46bd20cbd install.sh" | sha256sum -c
```

But I would like to use it with the `sha256sum` command *first*. So we have that using heredoc:

```
sha256sum -c << EOF
85762db0edc00ce19a2cd5496d1627903e6198ad850bbbdefb2ceaa46bd20cbd  install.sh
EOF
```

But now I would like this to be all on one line... So I tried:

```
sha256sum -c << EOF ; 85762db0edc00ce19a2cd5496d1627903e6198ad850bbbdefb2ceaa46bd20cbd  install.sh ; EOF
```

And it doesn't work. But *shouldn't* it work if the semicolon `;` means "we're going to run another command"?

Can we get it in that order, but written a different way to work on one line? If not, why can't we tell it what to do on each multiple line, but on one line?

Comment: The `echo` approach works and is portable, not requiring here strings. I don't understand what the problem is. Is it just that the command isn't on the left side?  The person running the script doesn't see that. Unless other aspects of the script depend on a specific shell already, it doesn't seem worth it to introduce that just to rearrange the command.

Comment: Re *"And it doesn't work."*: Can [you be](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/773418/edit) more specific? (But *** *** *** *** *** ***[without](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/131011)*** *** *** *** *** *** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the question should appear as if it was written right now).)

Answer (score 10):

> But shouldn't it work if the semicolon ; means "we're going to run another command"?

No, precisely because `;` means "we are going to run another command" but you are inserting it in the middle of a single command. Your command is:

```
sha256sum -c << EOF
85762db0edc00ce19a2cd5496d1627903e6198ad850bbbdefb2ceaa46bd20cbd  install.sh
EOF
```

That is one command, not many. You cannot break that with a semicolon and the way here docs work assumes separate lines, so you cannot do a here doc on a single line. Some shells, however, like `bash`, support [here strings](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Here-Strings) that are probably what you are looking for:

```
sha256sum -c <<< "85762db0edc00ce19a2cd5496d1627903e6198ad850bbbdefb2ceaa46bd20cbd  install.sh"
```

Here strings are just a quick way of passing a string as input to a command (or to  file descriptor, but never mind that). You can think of the above as the equivalent of

```
printf '%s\n' "85762db0edc00ce19a2cd5496d1627903e6198ad850bbbdefb2ceaa46bd20cbd install.sh" | sha256sum
```

Comment: then again, one can do `sha256sum -c <<EOF; echo hash checked.; <newline>85762db...<newline>EOF<newline>` (and even worse), so it's not exactly that the here-doc is exactly a part of a single unbreakable command...

Answer (score 3):

We can keep the code portable, **and** move the `sha256sum` command to the left column (though not before the `echo`) like this:

```
echo "85762db0edc00ce19a2cd5496d1627903e6198ad850bbbdefb2ceaa46bd20cbd install.sh" \
| sha256sum -c
```

This addresses the readability issue of the `sha256sum` being far on the right, away from the `echo`. Someone working with the code now sees this:

Comment: You can break on the `|`, so there is no need for `\ ` unless you _want_ it to be the first thing on the line. I assume you do, so I am not editing, just leaving the comment for others.

Comment: @terdon Yes, because then unless you move your eyes all the way to the right to spot the pipe, you just see an `echo` command followed by a `sha256sum` command.

Comment: Yep, hence the "I assume you do" :). Personally, I use indentation instead, but that is a completely personal preference. I just keep seeing people use `\ ` and then `|` or `&&` in places where it doesn't help legibility at all and simply adds a useless character, so I try to point out that it isn't needed. I completely agree this is a case that benefits from it.

Comment: @terdon Also, we have a requirement that the solution is on one line. We have one logical line, if not physical, with the continuation backslash.

Answer (score 1):

Semicolons and newlines are interchangable in some places, like at the end of a single command. But they're definitely not the same in every place.

So these are the same:

```
echo one
echo two
# and
echo one; echo two;
```

But while these work:

```
if true; then
   echo hi
fi
echo foo |
   wc
```

these don't:

```
if true; then; echo hi; fi
echo foo |; wc
```

And here-docs are an even more special kind of thing, they work based on lines, *outside the shell syntax structure*.

Which means that you can do things like these:

```
# semicolon and another command before the here-doc
cat <<EOF; echo there
hello
EOF

# pipeline continues past the here-doc
cat <<EOF |
hello
EOF
sed -e 's/$/ there/'

# multiple here-docs used on the same line
cat <<THIS; cat <<THAT
hello
THIS
there
THAT
```

So, your command line

```
sha256sum -c << EOF ; 8576...  install.sh ; EOF
```

has the shell wait for a here-doc ending with `END`, then run `sha256sum` with the here-doc as input, then run the commands `8576...` and `EOF`. You'll probably get "command not found" errors for the latter two.

As [terdon says in their answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/773418/here-document-as-a-single-line-command/773420#773420), a here-string is the one-liner version of a here-doc, one that works in most featureful shells, but not in the ones more strictly limited to the standard shell language (like Debian's Dash and Busybox's sh).

```
sha256sum -c <<< "8576...  install.sh"
```